Vector3 rotation influenced by parent of parent
I have the following function trying to rotate the last joint of a finger using mediapipe results. However, the joint rotates even when the actual joint has remained straight, but one other in its parents chain has moved. Any ideas on how to combat this?
function updateHand(results) {
    let landmarks = results.landmarks[0];

    let localVector7 = new THREE.Vector3(landmarks[7].x, - landmarks[7].y, - landmarks[7].z);
    let localVector8 = new THREE.Vector3(landmarks[8].x, - landmarks[8].y, - landmarks[8].z);

    localVector7 = localVector7.normalize();

    let vector8relativeTo7 = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(localVector8, localVector7);
    vector8relativeTo7 = vector8relativeTo7.normalize();

    let quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(hand.index[2].position, vector8relativeTo7);
    hand.index[2].setRotationFromQuaternion(quaternion);

    console.log("vector8relativeTo7: ", vector8relativeTo7);
}


You need to clarify a little, and reconcile your code with your question. You're making references to parents, but the only parenting your code implies is the relationship between vectors 7 and 8. I recommend simplifying the problem. Turn references into variables, and give all your variables names that are representative of their purpose. That will make it much easier to debug and understand what is happening at each step in your code.
